# What is the equation for the electric field made by a capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

In a capacitor, how can I calculate its electric field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field is geometry dependent. Depending on the geometry of intrest different techniques may be used. But in general one would solve Poisson's equation $\nabla^2\phi=0$ where $\phi$ is the potential, using the boundary conditions on the capacitor plates. Then the electric field is $\vec E=-\nabla\phi$.

For the simple case of large (infinite) parallel plates this gives $E=\frac{V}{d}$ where $V$ is the potential difference between the plates and $d$ is the perpendicular plate seperation.

Comment: My plates have an area of 3cm squared. Would I use Poissons equation?

Comment: If your distance between the plates $d$ is much less than the length scale of the plates ($\sqrt{3}$cm for square plates) then the electric field far away from the edges of the plates will approximately be that given by infinite plates. The exact electric field will be complicated to calculate and would likely require a computer.

Comment: d is not less than the length scale of the plates, so do i use Poissons?

Comment: Yes you would need to as the edge effect will likely be significant. This calculation will likely require a computer simulation and will likely not have an analytical solution.

Comment: Thanks - i need the electric field so I can find the acceleration of a particle in my electric field (a=qE/m) , so is there another way that doesn't envolve a computer simulation?

Comment: That said the infinite plate approximation would give a ball park estimation.

Comment: Thank you! So if I used E=v/d how accurate would my acceleration be? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: No worries, the exact acuarracy I am not sure of as this would require quite a bit of maths to estimate but the order of magnitude is likely correct. If your intrested this post goes into more detail on analytical solutions for parallel plates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618939/analytic-formula-for-finite-parallel-plate-capacitor-with-arbitrary-plate-distan

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem!

Comment: Also if this is for school they likely just want you to use $E=Vd$ but if it is for your own intrest or research then unfortunately you won't get much better than an estimate without using a computer for this problem.